# how to get weather icons using retrofit

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, retrofit, retrofit2

I am not able to get icons and summary when click on button to check any location data as when i click on button i m getting humidity pressure and temp but on adding summary and icons line in main activity app is crashing it returns null how to solve it.

Below is the main code on button click i am getting temperature and humidity but on add those two line of getting summary and icon, app is crashing   ,,,,,,,,,,,,below is main activity

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText editText;
     private Button button;
    private TextView responseText;
    ImageView iconImageView;
    TextView summaryTextView;

    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    init();}    
 private void init() {
    editText = findViewById(R.id.city_name);
    button = findViewById(R.id.city_click);
    responseText = findViewById(R.id.response_text);
    iconImageView = findViewById(R.id.iconImageView);
    summaryTextView = findViewById(R.id.summaryTextView);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                fetchWeatherDetails();
            }
        });
    }
    private void fetchWeatherDetails() {
        Retrofit retrofit = NetworkClient.getRetrofitClient();
        weatherapis weatherAPIs = retrofit.create(weatherapis.class);
        Call<Weather> call;
        call = weatherAPIs.getWeatherByCity((editText.getText().toString()),"c70504e5e7ee0c5962f9407a45a2e75b");
        call.enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response response, Retrofit retrofit) {
                if (response.body() != null) {
                    Weather wResponse = (Weather) response.body();
                    responseText.setText("Temp: " + wResponse.getMain().getTemp() + "\n " +
                            "Humidity: " + wResponse.getMain().getHumidity() + "\n" +
                            //  "icon:"+ wResponse.getWeather_().getIcon() +"\n"+
                            "Pressure: " + wResponse.getMain().getPressure());
                   summaryTextView.setText(wResponse.getCurrently().getSummary());
                   iconImageView.setImageResource(WeatherIconUtil.ICONS.get(wResponse.getCurrently().getIcon()));
                }}
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable t) {}});
    }
```

***below is Weathericonutil class to get icons***

```
public final class WeatherIconUtil {
public static final Map<String, Integer> ICONS;
static {
    Map<String, Integer> iconMap = new HashMap<>();
    iconMap.put("clear-day", R.drawable.ic_clear_day);
    iconMap.put("clear-night", R.drawable.ic_clear_night);
    iconMap.put("rain", R.drawable.ic_rain);
    iconMap.put("snow", R.drawable.ic_snow);
    iconMap.put("sleet", R.drawable.ic_sleet);
    iconMap.put("wind", R.drawable.ic_wind);
    iconMap.put("fog", R.drawable.ic_fog);
    iconMap.put("cloudy", R.drawable.ic_cloudy);
    iconMap.put("partly-cloudy-day", R.drawable.ic_partly_cloudy_day);
    iconMap.put("partly-cloudy-night", R.drawable.ic_partly_cloudy_night);
    iconMap.put("thunderstorm", R.drawable.ic_thunderstorm);

    ICONS = Collections.unmodifiableMap(iconMap);
}
}
```

***below is my weather api interface***

```
public interface weatherapis {
String api_key = "my key";
String BASE_URL= "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/";
// static Retrofit retrofit = null;
@GET("/data/2.5/weather")
Call<Weather> getCurrently();

/*
    Get request to fetch city weather.Takes in two parameter-city name and API key.
    */
    @GET("/data/2.5/weather")
    Call<Weather> getWeatherByCity(@Query("q") String city, @Query("appid") String apiKey);

}
```

*** currently class from models***

```
public class Currently {

@SerializedName("time")
@Expose
private Integer time;
@SerializedName("summary")
@Expose
private String summary;
@SerializedName("icon")
@Expose
private String icon;
@SerializedName("temperature")
@Expose
private Double temperature;

public Integer getTime() {
    return time;
}

public void setTime(Integer time) {
    this.time = time;
}

public String getSummary() {
    return summary;
}

public void setSummary(String summary) {
    this.summary = summary;
}

public String getIcon() {
    return icon;
}

public void setIcon(String icon) {
    this.icon = icon;
}

public Double getTemperature() {
    return temperature;
}

public void setTemperature(Double temperature) {
    this.temperature = temperature;
}

}
```

***below network client***

```
public class NetworkClient {

public static final String BASE_URL = "http://api.openweathermap.org";
public static Retrofit retrofit;
/*
This public static method will return Retrofit client
anywhere in the appplication
*/

public static Retrofit getRetrofitClient() {
    //If condition to ensure we don't create multiple retrofit instances in a single application
    if (retrofit == null) {
        //Defining the Retrofit using Builder
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL) //This is the only mandatory call on Builder object.
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()) // Convertor library used to convert response into POJO
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}

}
```

***crash log on geting suumary and icon in mainactivity ***

```
09-12 15:54:18.648 12336-12336/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
09-12 15:54:18.648 12336-12336/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.nv.thisisitman, PID: 12336
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String models.Currently.getSummary()' on a null object reference
    at com.nv.thisisitman.MainActivity$2.onResponse(MainActivity.java:63)
    at retrofit.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallback$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:86)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:754)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6239)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the response from debug.there is no summary in api response.

Check this example response: there is no summary

```
{
  "lat": 39.31,
  "lon": -74.5,
  "timezone": "America/New_York",
  "timezone_offset": -18000,
  "current": {
    "dt": 1646318698,
    "sunrise": 1646306882,
    "sunset": 1646347929,
    "temp": 282.21,
    "feels_like": 278.41,
    "pressure": 1014,
    "humidity": 65,
    "dew_point": 275.99,
    "uvi": 2.55,
    "clouds": 40,
    "visibility": 10000,
    "wind_speed": 8.75,
    "wind_deg": 360,
    "wind_gust": 13.89,
    "weather": [
      {
        "id": 802,
        "main": "Clouds",
        "description": "scattered clouds",
        "icon": "03d"
      }
    ]
  },
  "minutely": [
    {
      "dt": 1646318700,
      "precipitation": 0
    },
    ...
  },
    "hourly": [
    {
      "dt": 1646316000,
      "temp": 281.94,
      "feels_like": 278.49,
      "pressure": 1014,
      "humidity": 67,
      "dew_point": 276.16,
      "uvi": 1.49,
      "clouds": 52,
      "visibility": 10000,
      "wind_speed": 7.16,
      "wind_deg": 313,
      "wind_gust": 10.71,
      "weather": [
        {
          "id": 803,
          "main": "Clouds",
          "description": "broken clouds",
          "icon": "04d"
        }
      ],
      "pop": 0.03
    },
    ...
  }
    "daily": [
    {
      "dt": 1646326800,
      "sunrise": 1646306882,
      "sunset": 1646347929,
      "moonrise": 1646309880,
      "moonset": 1646352120,
      "moon_phase": 0.03,
      "temp": {
        "day": 281.63,
        "min": 271.72,
        "max": 282.21,
        "night": 271.72,
        "eve": 277.99,
        "morn": 280.92
      },
      "feels_like": {
        "day": 277.83,
        "night": 264.72,
        "eve": 273.35,
        "morn": 277.66
      },
      "pressure": 1016,
      "humidity": 55,
      "dew_point": 273.12,
      "wind_speed": 9.29,
      "wind_deg": 3,
      "wind_gust": 16.48,
      "weather": [
        {
          "id": 500,
          "main": "Rain",
          "description": "light rain",
          "icon": "10d"
        }
      ],
      "clouds": 49,
      "pop": 0.25,
      "rain": 0.11,
      "uvi": 3.38
    },
    ...
    },
    "alerts": [
    {
      "sender_name": "NWS Philadelphia - Mount Holly (New Jersey, Delaware, Southeastern Pennsylvania)",
      "event": "Small Craft Advisory",
      "start": 1646344800,
      "end": 1646380800,
      "description": "...SMALL CRAFT ADVISORY REMAINS IN EFFECT FROM 5 PM THIS\nAFTERNOON TO 3 AM EST FRIDAY...\n* WHAT...North winds 15 to 20 kt with gusts up to 25 kt and seas\n3 to 5 ft expected.\n* WHERE...Coastal waters from Little Egg Inlet to Great Egg\nInlet NJ out 20 nm, Coastal waters from Great Egg Inlet to\nCape May NJ out 20 nm and Coastal waters from Manasquan Inlet\nto Little Egg Inlet NJ out 20 nm.\n* WHEN...From 5 PM this afternoon to 3 AM EST Friday.\n* IMPACTS...Conditions will be hazardous to small craft.",
      "tags": [

      ]
    },
    ...
  ]
```

Comment: (This post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer, or just post it as a comment to the question).